# find local maxima and their indices in a python list

Tags: python, indices, maxima

I have a large data set and I am trying to find the local maxima and their indices. I have made it to get the local maxima but can't find a way to get their indices.
The thing is that I need the maxima only for positive values and we should ignore the negative values. In other words, it would be like splitting the list in several segments with positive values and getting those maxima.

For example, the list can be smth like this:
test_data = [2, 35, -45, 56, 5, 67, 21, 320, 55, -140, -45, -98, -23, -23, 35, 67, 34, -30, -86, 4, -93, 35, 88, 32, 98, -6]

My code is:
`

````
def global_peaks(test_data):
    counter1 = []
    index = []
    global_peak = []
    global_idx = []
    for idx, data in enumerate(test_data):
        if data > 0:
            counter1.append(data)
            index.append(idx)                                    
        else:
            if(len(counter1) != 0):
                global_peak.append(max(counter1))
                index.append(idx)
                global_idx.append(index)
            counter1.clear()
            index.clear()
    return global_peak, global_idx
```
global_peaks(test_data)

```
([35, 320, 67, 4, 98], [[], [], [], [], []])
```
result are correct when it comes to the values, but not the indices
````

Comment: I had a hard time figuring it out, but now it's clear: global_idx contains index, which is a mutable that you clear each time, so in the end global_idx only contains empty lists! That said, do you want global_idx to hold all indices of subgroups, or only the indices of each local maximum? In the first case, replace global_idx.append(index) with global_idx.append(index.copy()) .

Comment: Hi Swifty. Thanks for your comment. I need the global_idx to hold the indices of each local maximum, but the indices should refer to the test_data. I get indices of the counter1 list.

Comment: Hello. It seems @Flow solved your problem :) Be sure to accept their answer, and have fun on the rest of your work.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that. A total newbie in the business here. Had no idea I have to accept the answer and how to do that.  cheers mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def global_peaks(test_data):
    counter1 = []
    index = []
    global_peak = []
    global_idx = []
    for idx, data in enumerate(test_data):
        if data > 0:
            counter1.append(data)
            index.append(idx)
        else:
            if(len(counter1) != 0):
                global_peak.append(max(counter1))
                index.append(idx)
                global_idx.append(index)
            counter1.clear()
            index.clear()
        index.append(1) # <-- for demonstration
    return global_peak, global_idx

global_peaks(test_data)

# Output
([35, 320, 67, 4, 98], [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]])
```

One problem comes with appending a list (`global_idx.append(index)`), which is a mutable object. You are appending a reference to this list so your output will show whatever is within this list at the moment of outputting.
What you need to use instead is a copy of that list (`index.copy()`), though this still does not give you the result you need.
Why should these lines give you the corresponding index

```
index.append(idx)
global_idx.append(index)
```

This should give you its corresponding index:

```
max_idx = index[counter1.index(max(counter1))]
```

One comment on your general approach: Be aware that if you have 2 or more local maxima within a region of only positive values, you would only find a single one. Is that really what you want?

The full code looks like this:

```
def global_peaks(test_data):
    counter1 = []
    index = []
    global_peak = []
    global_idx = []
    for idx, data in enumerate(test_data):
        if data > 0:
            counter1.append(data)
            index.append(idx)                                    
        else:
            if(len(counter1) != 0):
                global_peak.append(max(counter1))
                max_idx = index[counter1.index(max(counter1))] # <- changed 
                global_idx.append(max_idx) # <- changed
            counter1.clear()
            index.clear()
    return global_peak, global_idx

#Output
globla_peaks(test_data)
([35, 320, 67, 4, 98], [1, 7, 15, 19, 24])
```

Comment: Hi and thank you so much for your answer. Yes, finding exactly the highest value within a region of positive values is what I need. Even if it is the only positive value surrounded by neg ones.

Comment: Oh, I manage to get the indices but they are from the counter1 list, not from the original test_data.

Comment: Thats strange, for me replacing `index.append(idx)
global_idx.append(index)` by `max_idx = index[counter1.index(max(counter1))] global_idx.append(max_idx)` works correctly.

Comment: Oh yes, it does actually. Thanks again Flow. Very much appreciated!